# How to extend TypeScript definitions or what is causing "duplicate identifier"

Tags: typescript, types, type-definition

I've found a few posts about TypeScript "duplicate identifier" errors; however, I'm still confused about the root of this problem.

I have a class in a module, which extends "spine.AssetManager" and my tsconfig.json file references the spine.d.ts file in the "files" section.   This allows my editor and tsc to understand the spine interface; however, it isn't clear to me why I can't have a class of the same name, but different scope defined. In my app.ts, I have code like the following, which causes no transpiler errors:

`renderer: spine.webgl.SceneRenderer;`

However, in my asset-manager.ts, the following causes the duplicate identifier error:

`export class AssetManager extends spine.AssetManager {...}`

How do I set things up so that I can use the "spine" definitions, including it's spine.AssetManager, but also extend it, and use my own "AssetManager"?  (I know I could just make mine unique, "MyAssetManager", but I'm hoping there is another solution.)

Comment: Are you looking for [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html)?

Comment: That does sound like what I need. Still studying it.  tsc is generating the definitions for the spine module, and I've created my own asset-manager.d.ts.  It appears that I have to redefine all of spine.AssetManager in my AssetManager if I use ```class AssetManager implements spine.AssetManager```.   Switching to "extends" just causes the duplicate identifier to happen again.   So, still more to figure out, but this has me pointed in the right direction.  Thanks!

Comment: It sure would be nice if an answer got posted rather than a vague link and commentary.